# how to plot time efficiency with python?

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I try to demonstrate the difference between 3 functions' efficiency with python.
these are the functions:

```
def sum_all_1(n):
    return n * (n + 1) / 2

def sum_all_2(n):
    sum_all = 0
    for i in range(n + 1):
        sum_all += i
    return sum_all

def sum_all_3(n):
    sum_all = 0
    for j in range(1, n + 1):
        for k in range(1, j + 1):
            sum_all += 1
    return sum_all
```

i try to put the times inside a pandas data frame and plot it:

```
N = 1000

def measure_time(n , func):
    times_list = []
    for i in range(1, n): 
        start = time.time()
        func(n)
        end = time.time()
        times_list.append((end - start))
        
    return times_list
        

first_function_times = measure_time(N , sum_all_1)
second_function_times = measure_time(N , sum_all_2)
third_function_times = measure_time(N , sum_all_3)

values = np.array([first_function_times, second_function_times,third_function_times])
values = values.reshape(-1,3)

df_times = pd.DataFrame(data=values, index = range(1,N), columns=['first', 'second','third'])
```

but most of the times, i got 0.0 in the difference between the "start" and the "end".
so when i try to plot it with seaborn I got:
[something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztem7.png)

the plotting code is with seaborn:

```
sns.scatterplot(data=df_times)
```

how could i solve this? thank you.

Comment: What do you want to solve? What would you expect to be different?

Comment: i want to plot 3 graphs of the different time efficiencies of the functions. the first function is constant, the socnd linear, the third squared. @mozway

Comment: Can you provide code for plotting?

Comment: i have added it. but i think the problem is in the saving the values more than the plotting. @matszwecja